# new lines for text box in php

Tags: php, html

I am having one HTML form, where in the address to be entered in text box 
and the PHP out produce the data  with following php code as:

```
$address =  $_POST["address"]; 

echo   $address;
```

And the out put comes in a single line like:

**The Manager, Scotia bank Ltd,Cincinnati Finance Center,26 W. Martin Luther King  Road, Cincinnati, Ohio 45268**

But  I need the out put in readable manner in 3-4 lines.

i.e  for each "," break / new line to be made - so that the out put would be:

**The Manager, 

Scotia bank Ltd, 

Cincinnati Finance Center, 

26 W. Martin Luther King  Raod, 

Cincinnati, 

Ohio 45268**

Can any body help me getting the soluation please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the output is displayed in a textarea:

```
$address = str_replace(",",",\n",$_POST['address']);
echo $address;
```

If its on HTML:

```
$address = str_replace(",",",<br/>",$_POST['address']);
echo $address;
```

Answer (score 0):

If `,` is the delimiter that you want to split the string then try with `explode` in php

```
$str = 'The Manager, Scotia bank Ltd,Cincinnati Finance Center,26 W. Martin Luther King Road, Cincinnati, Ohio 45268';
$arr = explode(',',$str);
print_r($arr);
```

[Check the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) for more

Answer (score 0):

Explode is the function you are searching for..

```
$str = 'The string';
$arr = explode(',',$str);
print_r($arr);
```

Learn more about [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) here.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like:

```
implode(",\n", explode(",", $string));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [explode](http://php.net/explode).Try this :

```
    <?php
$str= "The Manager, Scotia bank Ltd,Cincinnati Finance Center,26 W. Martin Luther King Road, Cincinnati, Ohio 45268";

$arr = explode(",",$str);

for($i=0;$i<count($arr);$i++)
{
    if($i==(count($arr)-1))
        $comma = "";
    else
        $comma = ",";
    echo $arr[$i].$comma."<br>";
}
```